# Parsing only new data from Kafka Tool

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I want to parse from the topic in Kafka tool data, which inserted into the topic yesterday. The topic contains more than 600bln data. And I need only new data. I have a parser that focused on timestamp, and if timestamp more than today's data it parses it. But it takes a lot of time.
For example

```py
for msg in consumer:
    s = msg[3]
    dt_object = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(s/1000)
    date1 = dt_object.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-06-04 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    if dt_object > date:
        print(date1)
        num_rows = num_rows + 1
        m = json.loads(msg.value)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python KafkaConsumer start consuming messages from a timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402672/python-kafkaconsumer-start-consuming-messages-from-a-timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [offsets_for_times](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html?highlight=timestamp#confluent_kafka.Consumer.offsets_for_times) to find the offset per partition for the earliest timestamp for which you'd like to consume, and then [seek](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html?highlight=timestamp#confluent_kafka.Consumer.seek) to that offset with the Consumer before consuming.

You can see an example of this here: 
https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/497

Comment: My topic contains 12 partitions, I couldn't understand the following documentation. What should I add?
 consumer.subscribe([param["TOPIC_IN"]])
# tp = TopicPartition(topic, 0)
# offsets = consumer.offsets_for_times({tp: 1591084496000})