# How to consume messages in last N days using confluent-kafka-python?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python

This question is similar to [Python KafkaConsumer start consuming messages from a timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402672/python-kafkaconsumer-start-consuming-messages-from-a-timestamp/46410623#46410623) except I want to know how to do it in the official Python Kafka client by Confluent.

I looked into the [Consumer.offsets_for_times](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#confluent_kafka.Consumer.offsets_for_times) function but I'm confused by that it accepts timestamps in the `TopicPartition.offset` field.

How is a `offset` equivalent to a timestamp?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did this recently for $work. You need to get the result of `offsets_for_times()`, then `assign()` that list to your consumer, and then call `consume()`. Importantly, *don't* `subscribe()` to the topic. (See Eden Hill's comment on https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/373).

You're right that the documentation for this function is somewhat confusing when it comes to defining timestamps vs offsets.

Update to answer followup question:

The difference to [How do I get the the offset of last message of a Kafka topic using confluent-kafka-python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71190043/how-do-i-get-the-the-offset-of-last-message-of-a-kafka-topic-using-confluent-kaf/71190206#71190206) is that rather than

```
topicparts = [TopicPartition(topic_name, i) for i in range(0, 8)]
```

you would do something like this:

```py
whents = datetime.fromisoformat("2022-01-01T12:34:56.000")
whenms = int(whents) * 1000   # to get milliseconds

topicparts = [TopicPartition(topic_name, i, whenms) for i in range(0, 8)]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info. How do I define `TopicPartition` params for `offsets_for_times()`? Can you elaborate? Thanks

Comment: I found that using timestamp as offset was actually implemented as part of [KIP-79](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=65868090#KIP79ListOffsetRequest/ListOffsetResponsev1andaddtimestampsearchmethodstothenewconsumer-offsetsForTimes()methodinConsumer) in 2016. It's an actual feature. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That method doesn't accept timestamps; only partitions that you want to find timestamps for.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#confluent_kafka.TopicPartition.TopicPartition

Perhaps you mean the *timeout* parameter?

Comment: That's exactly my point. It's what written in the document I linked, which is confusing.

Comment: I don't understand what you think is confusing. You define a list of TopicPartition objects and it returns timestamps for each. You would provide the `OFFSET_STORED` value for the offset parameter

Comment: No, the function does exact opposite. It will ”Look up offsets by timestamp for the specified partitions.”. Read the doc.