# How do I get the the offset of last message of a Kafka topic using confluent-kafka-python?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python

I need to retrive last N messages of a topic using `confluent-kafka-python`.

I've been reading https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html# for a day, but no finding any appropriate method for getting the offset of the last message, thus I cannot calculate the offset for consumer to start with.

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `get_watermark_offsets()` function of the Consumer. You call it with a list of `TopicPartition` and it returns a tuple `(int, int)` (low, high) for each partition.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#confluent_kafka.Consumer.get_watermark_offsets

Something like this:

```py
from confluent_kafka import Consumer, TopicPartition

# create the Consumer with a connection to your brokers

topic_name = "my.topic"

topicparts = [TopicPartition(topic_name, i) for i in range(0, 8)]

offsets = consumer.get_watermark_offsets(topicparts)

for p in enumerate(offsets):
    msg = "partition {p} starting offset {so} last offset {lo}"
    print(msg.format(p=p, so=offsets[p][0], lo=offsets[p][1]))
```